# RSS notification when somebody edits my question or answer?

Tags: discussion, feed, edits

I'd like to get a notification when somebody edits one of my questions or answers, but I'm not seeing that in my RSS feed.  Is there some other way to get this?  Have I configured something incorrectly?  Thanks!

**update:** Marc Gravell answered this in a comment so I'm popping it up here.  This URL (which hopefully will get its own link sometime) does the trick:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/%yournumber%?Tab=Revisions

Comment: (I added "discussion" as we're tying to mandate tags to clarify MSO; if this is actually "feature-request", please re-tag it)

Comment: @Mark: could you re-tag this "feature-request" please as I want it and I don't have tagging priviliges around here?

Comment: This does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edits to your posts are visible on the "recent" summary (the envelope at the top of the page), but not AFAIK via an RSS.

Comment: Is there a tab or direct url for this?

Comment: Or perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/%yournumber%?Tab=Revisions

Answer (score 0):

The RSS feeds take a while to get refreshed, you may need to wait a significant period of time before you see any changes.

Answer (score 0):

[Growl for windows](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/apps.aspx) can notify the user when new RSS messages are received. Mac version exists too

Comment: -1 This has **nothing** to do with the question being asked.