# How can I see my posts that were edited by someone else most recently?

Tags: support, edits, posts

I wonder how I can see my posts that were edited by someone else most recently. SEDE query or is that somewhere in the UI? The activity tab captures other kinds of activity, e.g. my edits.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RSS notification when somebody edits my question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5078/rss-notification-when-somebody-edits-my-question-or-answer)

Comment: @bobble no,  the question you linked pertains to notifications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For any particular site, on your Profile page, click the Responses link on the left, then click the Revisions tab, to display a list (in reverse date order, i.e., the most recent at the top) of all of the other members' revisions to your posts. For quick access to your list on this site, here's a [direct link](/users/current?tab=responses&sort=revisions).

Note this list includes the revisions that you were not even notified about due to them being considered too minor (e.g., editing a question's tags). For example, here is the list in my Meta profile:

[image: My profile page showing the list of other members' revisions to my posts on this site]

You could also have it highlight new items (starting from a certain date) by adding a `StartDate` parameter to the URL. It should look something like this:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=responses&StartDate=yyyy-MM-dd&sort=revisions
```

Comment: I did not know about the possibility to add highlighting using StartDate - that's interesting to know.
I have [searched a bit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=StartDate) to see whether this is documented somewhere - but I did not find it in some FAQ post, (status-completed) feature request or something similar.

Comment: @Martin I only discovered it by accident (clicking any of the 4 tabs will add the `StartDate` param to the URL). Based on my search, I _think_ that the Activity page replaced the "recent activity" feature mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5094/348196), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8129/348196), and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/27323/348196) that seem to have existed in the early stages of SO. I think that at some point during that process, they left the `StartDate` param supported in the "new" Activity>Responses tab.

Comment: @41686d6564 Thank you for your discovery & adding about it to my answer. I wasn't sure how to give appropriate attribution to you (since normally for me somebody comments about an extra detail, and then I add it to my answer while stating who it came from & with a link to their comment, with this helping to avoid confusion). As you didn't add any attribution to yourself in your edit, I thought you might not have wanted any. Nonetheless, since it also helped to highlight updates of my posts with just the tags being edited, I changed my answer's list image to include your edit summary.

Answer (score 4):

In the question you have mentioned [SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) query as one of the options. In this query, you can choose the post owner and the editor(s) that you do not want to see. (I.e., if you set both to your userid, you get edits on your posts by other users. You can do the similar thing for some other user, if you would like to see such edits)

SEDE query: [Edits on posts of the given-user - except self-edits](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1541735/edits-on-posts-of-the-given-user-except-self-edits?num=100&list=178179%2C183484) (In the parameters, I have added two editors as exceptions - just to illustrate that multiple users can be entered there as a comma separated list.)

EDIT: And here is a similar query which does not return multiple lines if there were edits to body, posts, tags: [Edits on posts of the given-user - except self-edits (by RevisionGUID)](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1541743/edits-on-posts-of-the-given-user-except-self-edits-by-revisionguid)<sup>1</sup>

Keep in mind that the data in SEDE are only updated once a week.

---

<sup>1</sup>This was the first time I tried to create an SQL query combining `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY`. I did my best to follow the advice from this answer on Stack Overflow: [How to use DISTINCT and ORDER BY in same SELECT statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5391564#5391642)

Comment: I suppose that it would be possible to create a similar query showing recent edits on all sites rather than on a single site. But I do not have that much experience with multisite queries - I'm not sure I would be able to write such query.

Comment: Probably should somehow return rows with distinct `RevisionGUID` to avoid duplicate revisions (e.g., [when someone edits both title and body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsKHb.png)). I would also use `ph.PostHistoryTypeId BETWEEN 4 AND 9` to support rollbacks as well.

Comment: @41686d6564 I have added a a parameter types - so that it is possible to choose various possibilities for PostHistoryTYpeId (and I have included the rollbacks). I am aware that there are multiple lines if there was edit to body, tags, title. I could try something like `DISTINCT ph.RevisionGUID` but things become a bit more complicated if we want to still have the list ordered from the most recent edits. [so]: [How to use DISTINCT and ORDER BY in same SELECT statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5391564)